# knockout checked binding - only one checked

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of Admins with a check box. I want to be able to select only one Admin.

**HTML:**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
<tr>
 <td>
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked: $root.selectedAdmin">
    <span data-bind="text: name"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody
```

**JS:**

```
function Admin(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

var listOfAdmin = [
new Admin(10, 'Wendy'),
new Admin(20, 'Rishi'),
new Admin(30, 'Christian')];

var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(listOfAdmin),
    selectedAdmin: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

For Example if Admin id 10 is selected the other admins should be deselected.

Is that Possible to do with Knockout?

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead of the checkbox if you want only one item selected?

Comment: I tried using Radio buttons as well, But I was not sure how I can only check one from the list of rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use radio buttons if you only want to allow multiple selection.

However if you still want to use checkboxes then on solution would be to combine the `checked` and the `click` binding:

Use the `checked` to check only when the current id equal to the `selectedAdmin` property and use the `click` binding to set the `selectedAdmin`.

So you HTML should look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, 
                                  checked: $root.selectedAdmin() == id, 
                                  click: $parent.select.bind($parent)" />
```

And in your view model you just need to implement the `select` function:

```
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(listOfAdmin),
    selectedAdmin: ko.observableArray(),
    select: function(data) {
        this.selectedAdmin(data.id);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjwvn/).

Notes:

- the `return true;` at the end of the `select` function. This is required to trigger the browser default behavior in this case to check the checkbox.
- the `.bind($parent)` is needed to set the `this` in the `select` function to be the "parent" `viewModel` object.